# When does passing lambda work and not work?

Tags: pandas

In certain cases you can pass in `lambda x` to chain functions in a dataframe like examples below:

```
df.loc[lambda x: x]
df.assign(lambda x: x)
```

but in certain cases, it does not work. If you take the example below, how would you chain `eq()`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],'b':[1,2,4]})
           a    b
0   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   [2, 3, 4]   2
2   [3, 4, 5]   4
```

If we were to for example call `explode()` on column a, it would return the below:

```
    a   b
0   1   1
0   2   1
0   3   1
1   2   2
1   3   2
1   4   2
2   3   4
2   4   4
2   5   4
```

But what if we wanted to see where `column a` equaled `column b`. The following code does not work. How would you chain `eq()`? When can you pass `lambda x: x` and when can you not?

```
df.explode('a').eq(lambda x: x['b'],axis=0)
```

Comment: btw you can also do `df.explode('a').query('a==b')`

Comment: Essentially, you can pass a `lambda` wherever a callable is allowed as an input...   You might be interested in [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html): `df.explode("a").pipe(lambda x: x.a.eq(x.b))`.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: But you could still use loc, though I agree that `query` is simpler: `df.explode('a').loc[lambda x: x['a'] == x['b']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lambda` will work wherever a function or callable is allowed as an input, for instance in the `df.apply` documentation:

```
DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, raw=False, result_type=None, args=(), **kwds    
Parameters
func: function
Function to apply to each column or row.
```

vs the `df.eq` documentation:

```
DataFrame.eq(other, axis='columns', level=None)    
Parameters
other: scalar, sequence, Series, or DataFrame
Any single or multiple element data structure, or list-like object.
```